# Efficient algorithm for Intersecting of two large lists

Tags: python, algorithm

Suppose two lists, a,b,c,d are int.

```
l1 = [[a,b],[c,d],...[x,y]] # len(l1) = 1 million
l2 = [[a,b],[c,d],...[x,y]) # len(l2) = 10k
```

Want

```
l3 = [[c,d],...[x,y]] # items [c,d] in l1 but not l2
```

Usage: l1 is my testing pairwise result, and l2 is the false positive. I want to remove false positive so I have true positive.

My attempt 1: double loops, slow ~30mins-ish

My attempt 3: set does not work

My attempt 2: double loops, but inner loop: when matching a item, remove it from both l2, so next iteration, will search less one item in l2, still slow 28min-ish

Any better performance is welcome.

Comment: Why doesn't set work? [a,b] is in both l1 and l2, but later you say it's only in l1

Comment: So, do you want to remove the items in `l1` which exist in `l2`? Your description implies that, but your example shows `[a, b]` in both lists.

Comment: What are `a, b, c, d` objects?

Comment: What Eric said. Are those a,b,c,d, etc supposed to be strings? If they are strings, ints, or some other immutable object (with a `__hash__` method), then you can use Eric's solution.

Comment: It's not totally clear from your description, but I guess neither l1 nor l2 contain duplicates internally. And if they do happen to contain dupes you'd be happy if those dupes were eliminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply convert your inner lists to tuples. Python lists aren't hashable, so you cannot put them into a set. I guess that's the reason why your 3rd attempt didn't work.

## Sets substraction

If your inner elements are hashable (e.g. `int`, `float`, `string`) and your inner lists are converted to tuples, you can convert your outer lists to sets and calculate `set1 - set2`.

```
import random

l1 = [[random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)] for _ in range(100)]
l2 = [[random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)] for _ in range(100)]

# set(l1)
## TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

set1 = {tuple(l) for l in l1}
set2 = {tuple(l) for l in l2}

print(l1)
# [[0, 9], [9, 7], [8, 7], [6, 7], [1, 4], [2, 7], [8, 9], [8, 7], [5, 0], [3, 8], [8, 1], [6, 3], [5, 2], [0, 5], [2, 0], [2, 4], [7, 8], [2, 3], [4, 6], [4, 4], [3, 1], [7, 5], [2, 6], [8, 5], [6, 0], [0, 0], [4, 8], [5, 2], [1, 8], [6, 8], [9, 7], [0, 8], [5, 5], [4, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8], [7, 8], [5, 3], [2, 4], [1, 0], [8, 8], [6, 5], [8, 9], [7, 0], [8, 0], [1, 1], [1, 3], [2, 6], [3, 8], [7, 2], [6, 8], [3, 9], [1, 9], [9, 8], [3, 8], [1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 5], [7, 8], [3, 9], [0, 6], [9, 4], [4, 6], [9, 6], [8, 9], [7, 2], [4, 6], [9, 0], [0, 7], [0, 1], [5, 6], [5, 1], [1, 5], [9, 1], [8, 9], [4, 5], [4, 0], [4, 2], [1, 7], [9, 7], [4, 7], [1, 6], [9, 2], [7, 0], [9, 8], [3, 7], [9, 9], [9, 9], [0, 7], [3, 0], [0, 4], [4, 7], [9, 9], [0, 4], [9, 1], [2, 9], [7, 7], [5, 6], [6, 4], [7, 4]]
print(l2)
# [[0, 4], [2, 0], [1, 2], [9, 0], [8, 0], [2, 0], [5, 6], [6, 2], [2, 5], [0, 1], [9, 7], [8, 1], [3, 5], [3, 5], [3, 1], [0, 4], [4, 1], [1, 1], [3, 3], [0, 8], [3, 3], [5, 8], [1, 3], [0, 9], [6, 6], [4, 4], [6, 9], [0, 4], [5, 5], [0, 8], [4, 5], [4, 1], [0, 8], [2, 2], [2, 9], [1, 1], [7, 2], [8, 3], [6, 3], [1, 0], [6, 0], [4, 8], [1, 4], [8, 2], [9, 7], [5, 9], [6, 3], [7, 2], [9, 7], [8, 3], [8, 6], [3, 6], [7, 8], [9, 4], [1, 2], [6, 1], [1, 7], [5, 0], [8, 6], [7, 5], [0, 0], [6, 9], [1, 3], [0, 0], [8, 9], [6, 2], [4, 6], [0, 9], [2, 8], [7, 1], [3, 1], [0, 9], [1, 5], [7, 8], [3, 6], [8, 6], [1, 2], [0, 6], [5, 2], [9, 3], [0, 6], [3, 2], [8, 6], [3, 1], [8, 6], [9, 6], [6, 2], [8, 4], [7, 3], [7, 9], [4, 9], [1, 3], [2, 2], [9, 2], [8, 4], [6, 8], [7, 6], [8, 9], [5, 2], [6, 4]]
print(set1 - set2)
# {(4, 7), (9, 1), (3, 0), (9, 8), (7, 7), (0, 7), (1, 6), (3, 7), (5, 1), (8, 5), (4, 0), (6, 7), (2, 6), (3, 9), (0, 5), (2, 3), (8, 7), (1, 9), (4, 2), (6, 5), (5, 3), (2, 7), (7, 0), (9, 9), (3, 8), (7, 4), (1, 8), (8, 8), (2, 4)}
```

You lose the order but the operation is really fast : the substraction required a few seconds for `len(l1) = 1 million and len(l2) = 10k`.

## List comprehension with set membership test

If you want to keep order and `l1` duplicates, you could iterate over `l1` and check if the inner tuple isn't in `set2`:

```
print(l1)
# [[2, 2], [3, 2], [7, 8], [0, 2], [4, 7], [3, 9], [8, 1], [4, 6], [9, 1], [8, 3], [7, 2], [2, 7], [1, 2], [0, 2], [9, 4], [5, 8], [9, 6], [3, 8], [8, 8], [1, 2], [7, 5], [0, 2], [0, 3], [3, 1], [0, 1], [5, 8], [3, 5], [6, 3], [7, 3], [9, 2], [6, 1], [4, 3], [6, 4], [0, 5], [9, 8], [6, 2], [3, 7], [4, 7], [8, 4], [0, 6], [0, 7], [5, 3], [2, 0], [0, 7], [2, 6], [9, 1], [0, 6], [5, 0], [7, 6], [8, 1], [3, 1], [9, 3], [2, 2], [4, 4], [3, 2], [2, 6], [5, 6], [3, 8], [3, 1], [4, 0], [2, 1], [6, 0], [4, 8], [3, 6], [4, 0], [9, 3], [6, 7], [7, 9], [4, 4], [4, 1], [5, 2], [6, 2], [2, 3], [1, 1], [9, 9], [9, 3], [9, 9], [7, 4], [2, 1], [6, 8], [5, 2], [4, 0], [4, 8], [4, 2], [5, 2], [6, 0], [5, 9], [9, 7], [1, 9], [7, 6], [1, 9], [7, 0], [9, 0], [6, 0], [7, 0], [0, 8], [8, 0], [1, 5], [8, 4], [7, 5]]
print(l2)
# [[3, 7], [7, 0], [8, 9], [6, 4], [9, 4], [7, 7], [8, 2], [6, 5], [5, 8], [5, 7], [5, 2], [0, 6], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 4], [9, 0], [8, 1], [5, 9], [4, 6], [9, 5], [6, 6], [3, 2], [0, 0], [2, 2], [3, 1], [2, 7], [3, 9], [9, 8], [4, 3], [8, 5], [2, 2], [2, 4], [2, 0], [0, 0], [4, 7], [7, 9], [2, 0], [7, 7], [4, 8], [0, 1], [9, 1], [1, 9], [8, 7], [7, 0], [5, 4], [2, 0], [4, 7], [3, 1], [6, 6], [0, 1], [3, 9], [8, 1], [1, 3], [9, 9], [8, 9], [6, 0], [2, 4], [5, 3], [5, 0], [4, 5], [4, 2], [3, 3], [1, 1], [3, 7], [5, 6], [8, 0], [8, 9], [5, 9], [4, 2], [4, 4], [9, 9], [5, 2], [3, 2], [3, 3], [7, 8], [2, 5], [1, 7], [5, 9], [9, 4], [7, 4], [2, 1], [0, 3], [6, 5], [2, 7], [6, 0], [7, 5], [8, 9], [3, 5], [2, 5], [4, 7], [5, 5], [4, 4], [9, 9], [0, 1], [2, 4], [7, 9], [8, 0], [7, 4], [0, 3], [9, 0]]
print([l for l in l1 if tuple(l) not in set2])
# [[0, 2], [8, 3], [7, 2], [1, 2], [0, 2], [9, 6], [3, 8], [8, 8], [1, 2], [0, 2], [6, 3], [7, 3], [9, 2], [6, 1], [0, 5], [6, 2], [8, 4], [0, 7], [0, 7], [2, 6], [7, 6], [9, 3], [2, 6], [3, 8], [4, 0], [3, 6], [4, 0], [9, 3], [6, 7], [4, 1], [6, 2], [9, 3], [6, 8], [4, 0], [9, 7], [7, 6], [0, 8], [1, 5], [8, 4]]
```

It should still be much faster than a double loop.

Comment: You should also mention this may not give the desired result if the items in the lists are custom objects. Two tuples with the same numbers, or strings will result to the same hash.

Comment: @Reti43: Indeed. I added a note. Also, custom objects could perfectly be hashable.

Comment: @Reti43 Good point, although I assume for the OP's use case that's a non-issue, and that each list only contains unique pairs, or if it doesn't dupes can safely be eliminated. But I wish the OP would clarify the details of the question...

Comment: @PM2Ring: Second code keeps duplicates and order.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. The point is the user will just have to implement `__hash__` appropriately then, which shouldn't be much of a trouble.

Comment: Actually, the second way, which also preserves order, is faster (see [timing code](https://pastebin.com/YAS5YsQP)). At the end of the day, you're only interested in making `l2` a set to take advantage of the O(1) look-up time.

Comment: @Reti43: Thanks for the benchmarking

Answer (score 0):

Since double loops on Would be `O(X*Y)` where X and Y are the lengths of your lists, the easier solution would be to sort both lists `O(X*log(X)) + O(Y*log(Y))` then iterate throught both at once like so:

```
i = 0
j = 0
while True:
  x_el = X[i]
  y_el = Y[j]
  # do something with it and increase i and/or j accordingly
  if i >= len(X) or j >= len(Y):
    break
```

Comment: This answer is a bit vague. And since the large list contains ~1 million pairs it's probably better to avoid sorting it, if possible.